# Athena federated queries against Postgres JSONB field

Tags: json, postgresql, federation, amazon-athena

It seems to me that Athena don't understand Postgres JSONB fields, and consider them VARCHARS. This means that any query involving json path expressions will be executed Athena-side, which again means that every row in database must be sent to Athena for evaluation.

How would it be possible to query Postgres JSONB fields with native postgres json functions instead?
Meaning how can I make an Athena query that uses native Postgres functions that are executed on Postgres to filter the rows returned?